# Possible to combine these 2 database columns into 1?

Tags: calendar, database-schema, recurring-events

I have a recurring event schema that has a `RecurrenceType` and a `RecurrenceMultiple` column. The `RecurrenceType` is a foreign key to a table that has these options (1) No Recurrence (2) Daily (3) Weekly (4) Monthly. `RecurrenceMultiple` is an integer that indicates what multiple of the recurring time frame each event occurs. a few examples

- RecurrenceType=1, RecurrenceMultiple=1 : One time only
- RecurrenceType=2, RecurrenceMultiple=1 : Every day
- RecurrenceType=3, RecurrenceMultiple=1 : Every week
- RecurrenceType=3, RecurrenceMultiple=2 : Every other week
- RecurrenceType=4, RecurrenceMultiple=1 : Every month
- RecurrenceType=4, RecurrenceMultiple=3 : Every 3rd month
- RecurrenceType=4, RecurrenceMultiple=12 : Yearly

I'd like to somehow combine these two columns in a way that I can infer the `RecurrenceType` allowing me to ditch the lookup table. I can't think of a good way to do this though and avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I've decided to use

A single column `RecurrenceFrequency` can be used if it's assumed that 0 means no recurrence, positive values mean a timespan of X days and negative values mean a timespan of X months

- 0 : One time only
- 1 : Every day
- 7 : Every week
- 14 : Every other week
- -1 : Every month
- -3 : Every 3rd month
- -12 : Yearly